# Execute a MATLAB file from code

Tags: matlab

How can I execute a MATLAB file (say "text1.m") from another MATLAB file ("main.m")?
I tried MATLAB's `eval` function but it didn't work:

```
evalc('K:\DOWNLOADS\experiments\bag_of_words\config_file_1.m');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_didn't work_"? What's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a [script](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/script.html) you can directly call it using its filename (without ".m") in another M-file script (similar to a function-call without any arguments or parentheses). If it declares a [function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/function.html) it should be in the MATLAB search path or in the current folder for you to be able to call the function. This is likely also the case for scripts.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer and person.  Thanks a lot Ole Thomsen Buus :)

Answer (score 1):

If the M-file is not on the path, there is a convenience function [RUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/run.html) to run scripts.